# On elegant use of Inner and Outer on tensors

Tags: list-manipulation, tensors

I have a collection of 5-element vectors each of which corresponds to an {x,y} location from a (20 x 21) grid. Because of that I represent that data as a (5 x 20 x 21)-sized tensor called `W`.

I also have a set of 128 (5 x 5)-sized matrices which I've packed as a (128 x 5 x 5) tensor called `R`.

I then want to compute for each vector in `W` and each matrix in `R` the product `Transpose[w].r.w` (which is a scalar) and obtain a (128 x 20 x 21)-sized tensor.  Finally, I only care about the sum over the 128 matrices, which will be a (20 x 21)-sized matrix.

I can compute that operation with the following command which leaves me very unsatisfied since it seems somewhat inelegant:

```
Total[Outer[#1.#2.#1 &, TensorTranspose[W, {3, 2, 1}], R, 2, 1], {3}]
```

It seems to me that there should be a way to not use `TensorTranspose`, and that the `Total` should be redundant if I were to use `Inner`.  However I don't see a clean way to use level specifications to get the answer I want.  Any ideas? (preferably ones that are efficient too!).

If you have to know, this implements a 5-sensor broadband delay-and-sum beamscanner.  `W` holds the steering vectors for each location to scan, and `R` are the covariance matrices for each frequency band.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but can't you sum the covariance matrices at the start?

```
result =  With[{r = Total @ R}, Map[#.r.# &, Transpose[W, {3, 2, 1}], {2}]]
```

This is several hundred times faster than the original.

Answer (score 2):

Take care!!   With the instruction:

```
Total[Outer[#1.#2.#1 &, TensorTranspose[W, {3, 2, 1}], R, 2, 1], {3}]
```

you are effectively doing:

```
Transpose[w].r.Transpose[w]
```

If you really want to do:

```
Transpose[w].r.w
```

Then you should:

```
Total[Outer[TensorTranspose[#1, {3, 2, 1}].#2.#1 &, W, R, 2, 1], {3}]
```